# I want to transfer the data between one fragment to another but I'm getting no views found Exception?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm transferring data from one fragment to another using bundle my code is perfectly fine but I'm getting No view found for fragment one[image]
I'm uploading the code of one fragment that is sending the data to another here it is
[image]
Also the code of one that is getting the data
[image]
now please tell me what should I do . I have a tab layout under which I have View Pager and in this view pager I have three different fragments and all I want to do is transfer data from one fragment to another … Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are using the wrong approach or the wrong way to sending data from one fragment to another. You are using [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/package-summary) with [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) so every tab item has its own fragment and you are calling the second tab item's fragment in the first tab item. That's not correct!

Use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for sending data between two fragments. Your issue will be resolve. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update getChildFragmentManager in place of getSupportFragmentManager inside Fragment

or just try the below way inside mainActivity and call from where you want

```
public void changeFragmentFrom(Fragment targetFragment, byte state) {
        try {
            if (defaultState == state)
                return;
            
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_layout, targetFragment, "" + state);
            ft.addToBackStack("" + state);
            defaultState = state;
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please try to implement this way if your requirement match in given link

[Can't use androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager in ViewPager2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526207/cant-use-androidx-fragment-app-fragmentmanager-in-viewpager2/58526385#58526385)

[Image not shown in ViewPager2 (when Fragment reopened)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391051/image-not-shown-in-viewpager2-when-fragment-reopened/68392107#68392107)

hope it may help you